# Angular 2+ ngModel variable with special symbol

Tags: angular, input, ngmodel

Angular can't understand property with '-' symbol in ngModel. I get error in the following input inside ngModel. How can i make this work without changing property name?

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="DRA0">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DRA-0 </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <input autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]='element.DRA-0' />
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: As per https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp Hyphens can be mistaken as subtraction attempts. Hyphens are not allowed in JavaScript names. You don't have control over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply wrap it with square brackets.

```html
<input autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="element['DRA-0']" />
```

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to accept it if it fits :)

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you could use string literals.

```
<input autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="element['DRA-0']" />
```